# How to change ActiveRecord's table name during runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am changing the `table_name_prefix` during running of a rails application (might sound weird, but really that's what I want). When the `table_name_prefix` changes for the `ActiveRecord` I reset the table names (`table_name` and `quoted_table_name`) by calling `reset_table_name`, and they change.. however I have another issue.

If the table name changes, after calling such a thing like count or a find the ActiveRecord object still operates with the table, which was used before.

How can reach to reset an `ActiveRecord` descendant, so that when the prefix, suffix, table_name changes it works with the new settings?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good god, why would you ever do this?

Comment: i don't know how you could do that, but that's some question !

Comment: @DonRoby suppose that you want to switch between datasets, which are distinguished based on table_name_prefix. It is like db sharding, but I do not want to have new database, I can use only one db with multiple datasets.

Comment: In case someone needs to play with something similar in the future, see this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537951/changing-table-name-at-query-run-time-in-a-rails-application/52539763#52539763

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the explanation for the described behavior. Although `reset_table_name` resets the table name computed from the prefix, suffix (and maybe other things too), the table is initialized when a model is used and a query is generated. `ActiveRecord` works "on the top of" `Arel`, a relational algebra gem. When an `ActiveRecord` model is used a table is created and filled `@arel_table` instance variable. This caching is for performance purposes. If one wants to recreate the arel table, it can be reset by calling `reset_column_information`. I needed to have both `reset_table_name` and `reset_column_information` in order to get a new table for the new table name. Probably I will have to worry about the performance, if I reset the table often.

Comment: Can you put an example on it? I want to do this for a bunch of models at the same time.