# Defining a Dynamic Table Name Prefix in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm using a Rails application to access a Dynamics NAV Database (today is called Dynamics 365 Business Central). In order to make it multi tenant, they partition the DB using table name prefixes ex: `Company 1$Warehouse Entry` or `Company 2$Warehouse Entry`.

I wanted to use a field defined in my `User` model in order to set the company name that it access.

In order to access the current user in the model I have used the following on application_controller.rb

```
before_action -> { User.current = current_user }
```

And then I set a base class where it declares the following instance method:

```
def self.set_company_name
  company = User.current.nav_company ? User.current.nav_company + "$" : "Company 1$"
  self.table_name = company + self.table_name
end
```

I also tried to use instance variables `@@company` but after reading I saw that table names in rails are cached.

What I have done works, but only if you restart the application. The table name doesn't change in runtime.

How can I make it dynamic? I saw this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493846/how-to-change-activerecords-table-name-during-runtime/) but the answer didn't show how to do this.

Comment: `Company 1$Warehouse Entry` and `Company 2$Warehouse Entry` are different tables?

Comment: Yes. Two different tables

Comment: ActiveRecord pattern pretends, at least in Ruby on Rails implementation, that every table on your database must be associate with only one model.There is a compelling reason to use the same user model class for two different tables?

Comment: Yes. they are the same model, just differs by the table name prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Dynamics 365 and I don't understand why you want to associate two tables to one model, but I have worked with [schemas/namespaces in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-schemas.html) for example: `config.users` where `config` is the schema and `users` the table name; so you can use it like `select * from config.users`.

Rails can easily adapt to this struct like you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838881/12063745).

Comment: schema/namespaces is not what I'm looking for... The problem is that the change is on table name, not on schema. Maybe there's a way to avoid caching table names in Rails.